# FromBody does not ignore properties decorated with JsonIgnore on POST

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, model-binding, .net-7.0

I'm building a controller that should recerive a `Workflow` type via the request's body, but it doesn't respect the `JsonIgore` attribute and throws a model validation error that says:

> "The Name field is required."

When I look into what body Swagger suggests then it's what one would expect:

```json
{
  "schedule": "string",
}
```

But even when I explicitly specify `name` in my request, it still does throw the same exception. Why?

---

This is my test setup:

```cs
public class Workflow
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Schedule { get; set; }

    // ...
}

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class WorkflowsController : ControllerBase
{    

    [HttpPut("{workflowName}")]
    public async Task<int> CreateWorkflow(string workflowName, [FromBody] Workflow workflow)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Do I have to create another class for the body or is there a way to fix that strange behavior?

Comment: Where is the name property set to required?

Comment: @itsdaniel0: I'm asking myself the same question. It's all I have. There's no _required_ word in the entire project.

Comment: Are you using nullable reference types?

Comment: @itsdaniel0: do you mean this setting `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` in the `*.csproj` file? Yes, I am.

Comment: This is a valid issue, and using a nullable type for the property is not the solution. For example in the case of a computed property (not nullable) which you want to have ignored, but can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JsonIgnore` will just ignore that property for serialisation, meaning it won't set it. Since you're using nullable reference types, the property `Name` is expected to have a value & model validation will take this into account.

You can either give it a default value

```cs
public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

Or make it nullable

```cs
public string? Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: That was tricky! Now with the `?` the error is gone ;D

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem when using a computed property. This property was not nullable and was computed to be based on another (non nullable) settable property.

When omitting the settable property I would get model binding errors on both properties which would be misleading to the client.

The only way to get around this in my case is use null coalesce despite the fact that none of the values are nullable:

```cs
class MyModel {
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [JsonIgnore] // This didn't help!
  public string FirstName => Name ?? ""; // This is the hack
}
```

Without the `??` hack, when `Name` was omitted from the request, you would get errors saying that `Name` and also `FirstName` were missing.